# How to initiate/send SMS from a HTML5 webpage using devices native functions?

Tags: iphone, android, html, sms, protocols

I am wondering how can I open the send SMS application by using a web control of a HTML5 page on Android and iPhone. I want to use the device native SMS sending app, with a prepopulated value from the web.

Comment: RFC5724 http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5724

Comment: Any information if that is in-built in todays devices?

Comment: I think iPhone is limited to just a number https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/sms.html

Comment: It looks like Android is limited to just a number - it will not parse the body into the created SMS message

Comment: On iPhone it only works if you format the number with international dialling code (eg. +43123333) and not with 0 in front (eg. 0123333). SMS text is not allowed - even number is then ignored.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Further to other answers I can confirm that smsto:555:bodytext does *not* work on an iPhone running iOS5.

What does work (and I've tested it) on Android is the format:

```
sms:444?body=hello
```

**Example:**

```
<a href="sms:444?body=hello">Tap to say hello!</a>
```

On iPhone the ?body=hello will prevent it working at all, and you should use just sms:555 instead.

sms:555

**Example**

```
<a href="sms:444">Tap to text us!</a>
```

Comment: Ben, I do not understand how can you claim that body attribute works in Android, it does not atleast in stock Android Browser and a bug12142 (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12142 ) exists for this which is still not resolved. What works is a URI with only the number, body attribute does not work

Comment: Hiya. The body tag definitely worked on the devices I tested with at the time, I should have written down which they were. It's possible that 'stock' Android doesn't support this I suppose.

Comment: Works fine both on Blackberry 10 and LGE LG-E610 (native browsers).

Comment: to make it work on iOS, use `sms:5555551212;body=hello`

Comment: can anyone tell how to do it in windows phone enviroinment?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the below and it works:

Using HTML Anchor tag:

```
<a href="sms:111?body=SUBSCRIBE">Subscribe</a>
```

Using JavaScript:

```
window.open('sms:111?body=SUBSCRIBE', '_self');
```

Answer (score 0):

With Android 3.0 SDK Google has started exposing API in HTML5 for device access. An example is listed [here](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/android-3-0-honeycomb-is-first-to-implement-the-device-api). It may not be enough for what you seek to do.

I dont know enough about iphone to advise either way.