# html5 send message in ios

Tags: ios, html

I have this code that supposed to send sms in ios

```
<a href="sms:1-111-1111;body=I made it!">Send location via SMS</a>
```

but this is not working as will the body text is empty

Answer (score 0):

Will not work for iOS 7. See [Apple URL Schemes - SMS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html).

There have been claims that this used to work for iOS 5/6 -

```
<a href="sms:1-111-1111?body=I made it!">Send location via SMS</a>
```

**Old threads**

[How to initiate/send SMS from a HTML5 webpage using devices native functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721437/how-to-initiate-send-sms-from-a-html5-webpage-using-devices-native-functions)

[How to pre-populate the sms body text via an html link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480462/how-to-pre-populate-the-sms-body-text-via-an-html-link/19126326#19126326)

Comment: it is the same problem the number show as 1-111-1111, and the text message is empty

Comment: @user3473821 Agreed, if you're on iOS 7. There have been claims that its deprecated. If you find a solution, feel free to add/edit this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The below format is working in iOS 8.1 ... might want to test in iOS 7: http://jsfiddle.net/2yjbG/

`<a href="sms:1234567900&body=Pre-populated">I pre-populate an SMS</a>`